# Pandas Trello JSON to XLS - how to add and flatten checklist objects?

Tags: python, json, pandas, trello

I need to convert the JSON export of Trello to XLS.  I found this elegant implementation with Pandas. It creates a table of cards and flattens card labels as a comma-separated list to one cell.

```
import simplejson
import pandas as pd
json_data = open('treelloin.json').read()
json_data = '['+ json_data + ']'
data = simplejson.loads(json_data)
json_data = simplejson.dumps(data[0]['cards'])
df = pd.read_json(json_data)
df["labels"] = df["labels"].apply(lambda cell: [row['name'] for row in cell])
df.drop([u'attachments', u'badges', u'checkItemStates', u'closed', \
       u'desc', u'descData', u'due', u'dueComplete',\
       u'email', u'idAttachmentCover', u'idBoard', u'idChecklists', \
       u'idLabels', u'idList', u'idMembers', u'idMembersVoted', u'idShort'\
       , u'manualCoverAttachment', u'pluginData', u'pos',\
        u'shortLink', u'subscribed', u'url'],inplace=True,axis=1)
df.to_excel('cards.xlsx')
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/ricardocabral/a8fbdea76dbae646df726686b5589604

Sample Trello JSON with several cards and checklists: 
https://pastebin.com/NuRF26Ez

**How do I add checklists data to it?** 
The perfect solution would be to create two columns: CheckedChecklistItems, UnCheckedChecklistItems, and put there a list of checklists items from all checklists in a card in a similar way as it's done with labels.

It should be easy to do with Pandas. Can anyone give me a hint - how? Like several joins on CheckList and CheckListItem IDs, or something like that.

**Expected output in CSV format** (see two columns added by me in the end)

Pastebin CSV: https://pastebin.com/T3MGNJjT
File for convenience: https://gofile.io/d/XPTrb4

Source Trello board for reference: 
https://trello.com/b/qBtTwPDN/test-board

Comment: kindly post your expected data output

Comment: Expected output in CSV format. See the checkedCheckListItems,UnCheckedCheckListItems columns added by me in the end:

Paste bin CSV: https://pastebin.com/T3MGNJjT
File for convenience: https://gofile.io/d/XPTrb4

Source Trello board for reference: 
https://trello.com/b/qBtTwPDN/test-board

Answer (score 0):

Trello's JSON is one-to-many data structure with complex structure. You need to have custom made `DataFrame`s to collect data from different levels.

I have made a repository on github that may help you to figure out how to proceed further:
[trello_json_to_csv example on github](https://github.com/deal2k/trello_json_to_csv)